# how to make portion of UILabel bold

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a uilabel like shown below

"Welcome **User**"
How it is posible?
Im using objective c XCode 8.0

Comment: Use attributed text for your label

Comment: Using Attributed String

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code :

```
NSMutableAttributedString *myString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Welcome User"];
[myString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17];
              range:NSMakeRange(9, 14)];
```